# Adjacency matrix from image file of plane map

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing

I have image files (PNG format) of plane maps of regions delimited by black borders

[image]

I would like Mathematica to compute the associated adjacency matrix for the contiguous regions in these maps.

So far I can find the regions using the command `MorphologicalComponents`, which associates an integer $1, 2, \ldots $ to the set of pixels corresponding to each region

How can I go on to compute the adjacency matrix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<< Combinatorica`;
i = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFZ3F.png"];
mc = MorphologicalComponents[i];
l = Flatten[Thread /@ ComponentMeasurements[MaxFilter[mc, 3], "Neighbors"] /. 
            Rule -> List, 1];
am = ToAdjacencyMatrix@FromOrderedPairs[l];
f[n_] := f[n] = Rasterize@ ImageAdd[
    Image[Unitize[mc - n] /. {1 -> {0, 0, 0}, 0 -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]}, 
          ImageSize -> IntegerPart@(ImageDimensions@i/10)], 
    ColorNegate@i]
k[i_, j_] := k[i, j] = k[j, i] = ImageAdd[f[i], f[j]]
mi = MapIndexed[Tooltip[#1 /. 
            {0 -> Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[]}], 
             1 -> Graphics[{Orange, Rectangle[]}]}, k @@ #2] &, am, {2}];
GraphicsGrid@mi
```

[image]

Or the simpler:

```
<< Combinatorica`;
i = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFZ3F.png"];
mc = MorphologicalComponents[i];
l = Flatten[ Thread /@ ComponentMeasurements[MaxFilter[mc, 3], "Neighbors"] /.
                                                                    Rule -> List, 1];
ToAdjacencyMatrix@FromOrderedPairs[l] // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very nice! Just wanted to add that equivalent functionality can be obtained in versions newer than 8 without loading `Combinatorica` by using `AdjacencyMatrix@Graph[l]`. (+1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this code isn't working as I'm expecting. For example, using the test image http://i.imgur.com/iwMCSeI.png I calculate by hand the adjacency matrix to be:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: but your code gives:


$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Sorry, the example image in my OP was a bad choice as I actually want to use more complex images like the example in my comment above.

Comment: @AthanasiosEvangelou It's difficult to fit any configuration. You may try something like `i1 = Binarize@Import["http://i.imgur.com/iwMCSeI.png"];
i = ColorNegate@Thinning@ColorNegate@i1;
mc = MorphologicalComponents[MaxFilter[ImageData[i1], 1] // Image];
l = Flatten[
   Thread /@ ComponentMeasurements[MaxFilter[mc, 1], "Neighbors"] /. 
    Rule -> List, 1];
(am = ToAdjacencyMatrix@FromOrderedPairs[l]) // MatrixPlot`

Comment: Thanks but this code is still not quite accurate enough. Here's another example of an image I would like to process: http://imgur.com/Kae9haU

I'm producing the source files myself so I'm can control parameters such as line thickness, resolution, etc. Do you have any tips on controlling some parameters of the source file to improve the accuracy of this code?

Comment: @AthanasiosEvangelou Questions here normally work the other way. You first work hard to define your problem, then perhaps you find someone to help you. Please define "neighbor", "black border" and state your max and min image, region and line sizes

Comment: @AthanasiosEvangelou Consider for example this http://i.stack.imgur.com/j2lPO.png

Comment: @belisarius Sorry for my lack of clarity. By "neighbor" I mean an adjacent region, where two regions are adjacent if they share a common border that is not a corner, where corners are the points shared by three or more regions. The "border" is the boundary of a region and is small relative to the regions, say $ 4-16px$ in width. The regions will be greater than say $60px^2$ and the size of the image about $600-1200px^2$. Thanks again.